# Sync from local git folder to remote folder

Tags: git, svn-repository

I want to know is possible to sync from local git repository to remote server.

1. I have git repository in our server on LAN
2. I have a git repository in Remote server like Godaddy or Amazon.

Is it possible to sync changes files from LAN git repository server to remote server repository for get updated files from any where? (Outside office)

Please provide any methods are available.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hari. It seems you need to `push` your repo to the remote. Tell us more about your context for more specific help.

Comment: Why not github?

Comment: @RomainVALERI - I want to sync local git repository to remote git repository for a particular time like cron job , is possible? Is possible how to do?

Comment: @Hari OK, so you also need to automate the process, but are you ok with the basic operation of (manually) pushing to upstream? Chances are both are already answered around here.

Comment: @RomainVALERI , Basic operation of git is fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+to+remote+cron

Answer (score 1):

If you have contrôle over the remote repository on your LAN, you could use a post-receive hook that will push to the external repo each time you push to the LAN repo :

First `ssh` to the server on your LAN and `cd` into the remote bare repo (eg : `your-repo.git/`).
Then create an executable file named `post-receive` in `hooks/` folder and paste this content inside :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Running post-receive hook'
git push ssh://godaddy...amazon...github..whatever/your-repo.git --all
git ush ssh://godaddy...amazon...github..whatever/your-repo.git --tags
```

That way, the external remote repo will always be in sync with the LAN remote repo.

I can provide further explanations if in addition you want to push changes directly into the external remote repo.

Comment: Can you provide detailed answers on how to automate sync between latest update from LAN repository to Remote (Godaddy or Amazon server ) repository